# Using Odata Model V2 with sap.m.list

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am using sap.m.list with smartforms in Splitapp. The problem is, I cannot use json Model for list since the binding context wont work for smartfrom.

But when I bind the list to Odata Model directly, the cache model data from the first `$skip0 & top=100` dont let me filter data. No matter if I call the read function of odata Model again, it will fetch the data but the old cache data remains there and in the list.

I tried clearing the cache model data with refresh(true,true) but it triggers the same `$count and $skip0 & top=100` again.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show a [mcve]. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the filters on binding level

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding/methods/filter

In a controller it works this way (assuming your Entity has property Prop:

```
oList.getBinding('items').filter( new Filter('Prop', FilterOperator.EQ, 'someValue' );
```

Or, in an XML view:

```
<List items="{path: 'EntitySet',  filters: [{ path : 'Prop', operator : 'EQ', value1 : 'someValue'},...] }”>
```

also have a look at [Filter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter) and [FilterOperator](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator)

Comment: Wont this filter the data in the list rather than calling the service again?

Comment: This will call the service with additional $filter=… request parameter. Unless you set binding parameter to execute filters client side.